# Why can't we compute this series using Riemann's sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Consider a series,
$$S=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

Which can also be written as,
$$S=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{2n}{(4r+1)(4r+3)}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$
Substituting
$$\frac{r}{n}=x,r=nx,\frac{1}{n}=dx$$
Gives,

$$S=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2n}{(4nx+1)(4nx+3)}\cdot dx$$

Which gives,
$$S=\frac{\log(12n+3)-\log(4n+3)}{4}$$

As $n$ goes to infinity $S$ goes to $\frac{\log{3}}{4}$.

But [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) states the sum to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$. I can't figure it out that what am I missing in this approach? Can it be solved using Riemann's sum?

Comment: The integral  is already supposed to be the limit of the sum. You can't have  $n$ inside your integral, only $x$ and you should not take the limit of the integral.

Comment: I don't see how you get $S,$ sorry. There shouldn't be any $n$ in your integral, since otherwise, you have, for each $n,$ that the sum is the Riemann sum for a different integral, and hence they do not necessarily converge. Smaller $\Delta x$ converges to the integral when you have one integrand.

Comment: @Lelouch  why is this incorrect? If we solve the integral without putting the limit? Will it be correct? After it will be a function of $n$ and then why can't we put $n$ tending to infinity?

Comment: You are essentially doing the equivalent of: "If $a_{m,n}$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{m,n}=b_m$ for each $m,$ then $$\lim_{m\to\infty} a_{m,m}=\lim_{m\to\infty} b_m.$$ But this isn't true, as can be seen by $a_{m,n}=2^{m-n}$ and $b_m=0.$

Comment: In your case, $a_{m,n}$ is the Riemann sum for $f_m(x)=\frac{2m}{(4mx+1)(4mx+3)}$ and $\Delta x=\frac1n.$

Comment: Was talking the integral line, but OP fixed it now. @XanderHenderson

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how do you know that $m$ amd $n$ will be different in this case? In calculation of $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i}$, $\frac{1}{n}=dx, \frac{i}{n}=x$ gives correct solution. Why not here?

Comment: Basically, you can only have a sum involving the ratio $\frac{r}{n}$ so that it becomes $x$ in your final integral (and the $\frac1n$ in front of the partial sum).

Comment: $\frac1{n+i}=\frac1n\frac1{1+i/n}$ is a Riemann sum for one function, $f(x)=\frac1{1+x},$ which does not depend on $n.$ Your Riemann sums are for different functions.

Comment: I would add, you have a lot of abuse of notation, like $dx=\frac1n.$ $dx$ is not a number. Or have $S=$ an integral of a function dependent on $n,$ but previously define $S$ as the l8mkt as $n\to\infty$ of another expression, so that it can't be a value depending on $n.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason to think that a sequence of Riemann sums for **different** functions converge, even if $\Delta x\to 0.$

Here, you have a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{2n}{(4nx+1)(4nx+3)}.$ And you have the Riemann sum of $f_n$ for $\Delta x=\frac1n.$

If we write $S_{n,m}$ as the Riemann sum for $f_n$ with $\Delta x=\frac1m,$ then you want:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_{n,n}.\tag1$$

Now, what we know is that, for each $n,$ $$\lim_{m\to\infty} S_{n,m}=\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx\tag2$$

But there is no reason to think that helps us compute the limit $(1).$ This is because the convergences in $(2)$ are not uniform. In particular, since $f_{n}(0)=\frac{2n}3\to\infty,$ we need $\Delta x$ to be small relative to $f_n(0)$ to get close to the limit integral.

---

What you are essentially saying is that if we have a double sequence $a_{n,m}$ and a sequence $b_n=\lim_{m\to\infty} a_{n,m},$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n.$$

But this isn't true in general, as can be seen with $a_{n,m}=2^{n-m}.$

Then $\lim_m a_{n,m}=0$ for each $n,$ but $\lim_n a_{n,n}=1.$

You can only do this if the limits converging to $b_n$ are **uniform.** But there is no reason to think your integrals converge uniformly, and, due to the unbounded nature of $f_n(0),$ actual reason to believe they are not.